# Как исправить ошибку cannot use object of type stdClass as array?

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет!
Изучаю laravel второй день, никогда раньше не пользовался фреймворками, но писал на чистом php около 10 лет.

Сделал тестовую страницу на которую пытаюсь вывести несколько записей из БД. Сначала делал все как везде пишут то есть через ORM и все работало.
Но затем захотел join'ить вторую табличку хотя бы в отношении один к одному, решил попробовать для начала raw sql

И вот что вышло

В модели

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;

class Item extends Model
{
    //

    public function getItemsWithCpu()
    {
        $items = DB::select('select i.*, c.title as cputitle from items i join cpus c on i.cpuid=c.id');
        return $items;
        //return $this->hasOne('Cpu'); 
    }
}
```

В контроллере

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Item;
use DB;

class HomeController extends Controller {


    public function index(Item $itemModel)
    {
        //$items = array();
        //$items[] = ["id" => 1, "name" => "продукт 1", "descr" => "Отличный продукт 1"];
        //$items[] = ["id" => 2, "name" => "продукт 2", "descr" => "Отличный продукт 2"];
        //$items = Item::all();
        $items = $itemModel->getItemsWithCpu();
        //dd($items);
        $data = [
        'title' => 'Каталог - список', 
        'pagetitle' => 'Каталог',
        'subtitle' => 'Список продуктов',
        'items' => $items
        ];

        //dd($data);
        return view("incs.itemlist", $data);
    }
```

И в шаблоне

```
@extends('master')

@section('cont')
     <h2>{{$subtitle}}</h2>

        @foreach($items as $item)  
            <div><a href="/items/{{$item['id']}}">{{$item['title']}}</a></div>
        @endforeach

@endsection
```

Пока данные получались просто через `$items = Item::all();` все работало. А теперь ругается как я понимаю на `foreach`

> FatalErrorException in
>   858e3d2b2b5779e85b41b79821e86c9637f363f2.php line 5:
>   Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

В `dd()` контроллере данные есть. Почему их нельзя обойти `foreach`, а чем можно?

Answer (score 1):

Пофиксилось оказалось в `foreach` полученный `$item` имеет поля как у объекта, а не массива.